# angularjs and codeigniter pagination

Tags: angularjs, codeigniter, pagination, codeigniter-restserver

I use angularjs for UI and codeigniter for backend(REST Server). When I'm using only codeigniter I know how to make pagination, but I can figure out how to make for this situation. For that purpose I make one function to test that.

So on REST Servers (codeigniter) I made function for testing:

```
    $this->load->library('pagination');

    $config['base_url'] = 'http://localgost/test';
    $config['total_rows'] = 200;
    $config['per_page'] = 20;

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $links = $this->pagination->create_links();
    $this->response($links, REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);
```

And on UI side (angularjs) I get string on HTTP request:

```
<strong>1</strong><a href="http://localhost/test/20" data-ci-pagination-page="2">2</a><a href="http://localhost/test/40" data-ci-pagination-page="3">3</a><a href="http://localhost/test/20" data-ci-pagination-page="2" rel="next">&gt;</a><a href="http://localhost/test/180" data-ci-pagination-page="10">Last &rsaquo;</a>
```

But I cannot figure out how to convert this string to pagination button.

Does anyone know how I can make that and if is possible? If I success with this test I will easy make pagination for all my pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have got the same issue, i use jquery to solve it :

create a div tag to display pagination buttons

```
<div class="pagination"></div>
```

and use jquery:

```
jQuery('.pagination').html(data.pages);
```

and in codeigniter try to use angular url as base_url :

```
$config['base_url'] = '#/users;
$config['total_rows'] = 100;
$config['per_page'] = 10; 
$config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
$config['uri_segment'] = 4;
```

Comment: where did you write this code of jQuery? In angular view, angular controller, and how? Can you show me that part of code cause I understand rest except jQuery.

Comment: @sasa in angular controller just after getting response from server

Comment: I did that but I always get first page as active, when I click on another page I change my URL but still first page is active and no linked?

Comment: $config['uri_segment'] = 4; this value varies according to your url

Comment: It doesn't work. Also I can't use html(data.pages) cause is undefined. I use  only html(data). Do I give good response, first create link then response? Can you upload somewhere your code?